# Icon Information on google maps

Tags: android

I want to be able to show the name and address of an icon that I have added to my android map in a textview, so that when the user taps on an icon the name and address appears in a textview.  Currently I have dialog box, but he problem with this is that I intend to add a direction button in the textview as well. If anyone can help it would be apreciated, or point me to a helpful tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make use of this awesome, awesome library: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

It allows you to have pop-up balloons when the user clicks on an Overlay in the map. Then when the user clicks on the pop-up balloon, you can display whatever view that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Zarah, But I managed to work it out.Sorry for the late reply. If you need to know the solution, send me an email and I will send it to you.